# Combining Bitmaps / ImageLists (Win32)

Tags: c++, graphics, winapi, imagelist

Is it possible to create an image list from multiple bitmaps, or to combine multiple image lists into one.

For sake of simplicity, same element dimensions and transparent color could be assumed.

Reason: I am currently dealing with a very long image list containing four groups of icons and notable "reserved" areas between them. For editing it would be easier to split into four bitmaps, combine them on the fly and calculate icon indices dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ImageList_Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761512(VS.85).aspx) can add a bitmap with several images to an existing image list.  Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I've finally got it working using `ImageList_AddMasked` and using `ILC_MASK` for the new image list. (I couldn't get the transparent color to work with `ImageList_Add'). Thanks!